# visual analogue scale psychopy

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm developing a metacognition experiment in PsychoPy (v. 1.90.1) and I need a visual analogue scale to measure confidence. However, I can't find a way to remove the numeric values (`0` and `1`) from the extremities of the Psychopy VAS. 
Is there any way to hide them?

I need the word labels (`"Not at all confident"`, `"Extremely confident"`) but I would also like to have the answers recorded on a `0-100` scale (or an equivalent `0-1`) as the analogue scale does (so switching to categorical wouldn't do).

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Sonia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/ratingscale.html), particularly `labels` and `scale`. This is one solution:

```
# Set up window and scale
from psychopy import visual
win = visual.Window()
scale = visual.RatingScale(win, 
    labels=['Not at all confident', 'Extremely confident'],   # End points
    scale=None,  # Suppress default
    low=1, high=100, tickHeight=0)

# Show scale
while scale.noResponse:
    scale.draw()
    win.flip()

# Show response
print scale.getRating(), scale.getRT()
```

Comment: Indeed, I did not know that the builder version ignores the labels you include, so adding them in a code component solved the problem - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in the new [Slider](https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/blob/master/psychopy/visual/slider.py), which is included in the current PsychoPy beta versions and will be part of the next release. Here is a Python 3 code example how to use it:

```
from psychopy.visual.window import Window
from psychopy.visual.slider import Slider

win = Window()
vas = Slider(win,
             ticks=(1, 100),
             labels=('Not at all confident', 'Extremely confident'),
             granularity=1,
             color='white')

while not vas.rating:
    vas.draw()
    win.flip()

print(f'Rating: {vas.rating}, RT: {vas.rt}')
```

Before re-use, you will have to call `vas.reset()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip - I have been considering trying out the beta for a while. I haven't done it yet as I structured the majority of the experiment in psychopy2 - if I can pick your brain for a second, do you think there is any advantage in using the slider over the classic VAS? I'm having some issues in customising other aspects of it (i.e. including a random starting point at each trial, increasing the speed of the 1 step increment so that subjects can use the arrows to answer and not take forever) and I would be willing to switch in case the slider could solve them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally the `Slider` is much more lightweight and easier to customize than the `RatingScale`, and supports vertical scales as well. However, it does not allow for keyboard control (yet), so this might be a deal breaker for you.

Answer (score 1):

Might I extend @hoechenberger's answer to add support for

1. the randomised start on each trial (set `markerPos` to a random val in units of the tick marks)
2. keypress support (just use keys to adjust `markerPos` and when you're done assign that to `rating`)
3. custom step sizes (when you've understood (2) then this is probably obvious)
4. Python2.7 (no need to force Py3.6 here :wink: )

Here's the code:

```py
from psychopy import visual
from psychopy import event
from numpy.random import random

stepSize = 2

win = visual.Window()
vas = visual.Slider(win,
             ticks=(0, 1),
             labels=('Not at all confident', 'Extremely confident'),
             granularity=1,
             color='white')

for thisTrialN in range(5):
    vas.reset()
    vas.markerPos = random()  # randomise start
    while not vas.rating:
        # check keys
        keys = event.getKeys()
        if 'right' in keys:
            vas.markerPos += stepSize
        if 'left' in keys:
            vas.markerPos -= stepSize
        if 'return' in keys:
            # confirm as a rating
            vas.rating = vas.markerPos
        # update the scale on screen
        vas.draw()
        win.flip()

    print('Rating: {}, RT: {}'.format(vas.rating, vas.rt))
```

Comment: If ticks are (0,100) then you could set markerPos to be `random()*100` or for (1,100) you would need `random()*99+1`. The point is, the `markerPos` is set in whatever units the low/high tick marks have

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks a lot for this - I ended up using markerStart = random.uniform(0, 1) for the random start. I tried running your version of the VAS (as a code component, initialised at the beginning of the routine) and it returned the following error: module object has no attribute "Slider". Also, I suspect that my issue with the keyboard is related to the lack of sync between keyword and screen rather than being a scale issue per se (I tried it several times and sometimes it follows the arrows, sometimes it remains stuck, apparently randomly) - so I might not need to change the increments.

Comment: Slider only exists in PsychoPy3 upwards.

Comment: I see, I thought the new Slider didn't take keyboard answers but only mouse (and there is a slider marker option in psychopy2) - sorry about that and thanks  lot for the code!